# Nested Mongoose Schema of same type

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have to create a mongoose schema. For example, I have a collection named "categories" in which parent categories are stored. And a parent category can have multiple sub-categories.

So the category structure is the same for the parent and child category.

Please help anyone how to create schema for this structure. A sample response is below:

```
{
"id": "category_id_123"
"name": "General",
"parent_id": null,
"childs": [
    {
        "id": "category_id_124",
        "name": "General Knowledge",
        "parent_id": "category_id_123",
    },
    {
        "id": "category_id_125",
        "name": "Math",
        "parent_id": "category_id_123",
    },
]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that I accomplish similar task.

```
router.put('/addchild', (req, res, next) => {
    Parent.findById(
            req.headers.uid // Id of the parent
        )
        .then((parent) => {
            return parent.updateOne({
                $addToSet: {
                    child: req.body
                }
            }).then(() => {
                res.status(200).send({
                    message: 'child added'
                })
            })
        }).catch(() => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: 'child adding error.'
            })
        })
})
```

Here is relevant schema structure

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const parentSchema = new Schema({
     _id: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    createIndex: true,
    required: true,
    auto: true
},
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    match: /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/
},

child: [],

})
module.exports = mongoose.model('Parent', userSchema, 'parent')
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Yes, this is helpful for me. Can you please share the Schema structure also?

Comment: I need your help. How can I contact you?

Comment: How can I help you? How can I improve my answer and What are the details that you need to clarify?

Comment: Actually, I have a single API to add category and sub-category both. If request's body contain parent id, then I have to check the first parent exists or not. If the parent does not exist in db then need to add as a parent else needs to add in its parent's childs array.

Comment: I think my answer fits with your requirements all you need to do is customize some parts. Here is what my code does. First, get parent by id and then which coming from request and then update parents ' child with the value coming as the request body.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215755/discussion-between-ransaka-ravihara-and-nitin-agam).

Comment: Finally, after some time my problem has been solved. @Ransaka Ravihara Thank you for your time.